# How to link an external .otf file in p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I am trying to link a font file to a p5.js sketch, using a url so I can upload it on codepen.io, where you have to pay to upload files. The file is not available on google fonts as it is custom.

I tried putting the link in the the load font function like this:

`loadFont(url);`

but an error appears saying that the file could not be found. I uploaded the file to github and tinyupload, here are the links:

[Github](https://github.com/Tudor0404/files/blob/master/matrix-code-nfi.otf)

[TinyUpload](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=84191594828203269883)

[minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://codepen.io/poptudor/pen/MzLgWb)

Comment: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadFont

Comment: Can you please link to a [mcve] running in codepen?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I tried doing that already, it didn't work as the url is not directed at google fonts, and the file is not local.

Comment: @KevinWorkman done, remove all the settings to do with text and preload to make the text default.

Comment: The URL you're trying to load as a font is not a font. That is a web page. Also your script element isn't loading the p5js library atm, you closed `<script>` before the src attribute.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I fixed the code, I know the link is not a font file, that is my question, I also tried using the download link from TinyUploads.

Comment: loadFont needs a real, normal font url. So have your font on a real URL, not on a pay-wall host. Don't own a server? Good news: use github or gitlab. Can't do that because the font itself is on a locked down license? Then its license probably forbids you from using it online at all anyway

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans how would I be able to view the full .otf file on github, when trying to view it raw it downloads the file, I tried using that link but it still doesn't work. I don't think the file is on lock down as the file is available for personal use.

Comment: you put your files on github. Github gives you free hosting through github pages. You use the .otf file link from that hosted version. Don't use "the github.com" link. For example, I won't use https://github.com/Pomax/CFF-glyphlet-fonts/blob/gh-pages/binaries/customfont.otf because that's my code repository. I use https://pomax.github.io/CFF-glyphlet-fonts/binaries/customfont.otf because that's the hosted copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740553/mike-pomax-kamermans) already answered in the comments, but I figured I'd expand:

First, you need to make sure you're using a file host that doesn't hide your files behind a download page. You're getting pretty close by using the `https://github.com/Tudor0404/files/blob/master/matrix-code-nfi.otf?raw=true` link, but you still have another problem.

You need to get into the habit of looking at your [developer tools](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools). This is where errors and network problems will show up.

If you look at your developer tools, you'll see this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
'https://github.com/Tudor0404/files/blob/master/matrix-code-nfi.otf?raw=true' 
from origin 'https://s.codepen.io'
has been blocked by CORS policy:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

You're getting a CORS error (this is a good place to start your google search) which basically means that your file host (in this case, GitHub) is disallowing access to files from other domains (in this case, CodePen).

From what I understand, you shouldn't link directly to your files in your GitHub repo like this. If you need to host them, you could use something like [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/). (GitHub Pages allows CORS by default).

Of course, if you're setting up GitHub Pages, then you could use that to host your P5.js sketch and you wouldn't need CodePen anymore. (Unless you wanted to use it as a code editor.)